# Parsing JSON in email using SSJS and Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

This is my JSON request :

```js
{
  "definitionKey": "SSJSTEST19",
  "recipient":
  {
   "contactKey": "007",
    "to": "sourabxxxxx",
    "attributes": {
     "EmailAddress": "sourabxxxxx",
    "SubscriberKey": "Sourab",
    "CUSTOMERNR": "123678",
    "FirstName": "Sourab",
    "Packages": [
         { "Name" : "Entertainment",
           "Price" : "15 €",
           "PaymentDate" : "01.07.2020"
},
{ "Name" : "Cinema",
           "Price" : "15 €",
           "PaymentDate" : "01.07.2020"
}
]     
      }

  }
}
```

Here is my Code :

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <tr>
   <td align="center">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="550">

      <tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #4a4a4a; padding:px; line-height:24px; background:#F9F9F9;">
%%[
var @MyArray,@Array,@AllPackages,@email,@contactkey ,@First_Name,@CustomerNumber 
set @email= emailaddr 
set @contactkey = AttributeValue("Contact_Key") 
set @CustomerNumber = AttributeValue("CUSTOMERNR") 
set @First_Name = AttributeValue("FirstName") 
set @AllPackages = AttributeValue("Packages") 
]%%

<div style="text-align: right;">Kundennummer: %%=V(@CustomerNumber)=%%</div>
<br>
<b>Hallo %%=V(@First_Name)=%%</b>,<br>
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
 var arr = [];
 var jsonString1 = Variable.GetValue("@AllPackages");
 arr.push(Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonString1).message.views[0].content);
 Write(Stringify(arr));
 Variable.SetValue("@Array",arr);
</script> 

%%[
SET @MyArray = @Array 
]%%
<br>
%%=v(@MyArray)=%%
<br>

       </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

**Result - After triggering the email, the array yields [null] result.**

Comment: As a best practice, do not use SSJS in emails. 

An alternative specifically for your usecase of JSON parsing is GTL / Guide Template Language. Eliot Harper has a good example here:
https://github.com/eliotharper/gtl-demo

Comment: I used GTL, it works only when I pass the values explicitly in the code. I cannot fetch this array which comes in the form of nested data in JSON.

Comment: Hi, so what you're saying is, you can get to the "recipient" object, but not the "packages" array with GTL?

Comment: No.. I meant I cannot access "Packages" array using GTL.

Comment: I think we mean the same :)
It should be possible. Check this thread:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246729/using-gtl-to-display-data-from-nested-json-arrays

Comment: @JonasLamberty - The best practice is NOT to absolutely never use SSJS in emails. The best practice is to consider the usage. AMPscript is usually more direct and easier to precompile for simpler tasks. SSJS is inheritly more complex/dynamic so it is harder to precompile.  The best practice as well is to not mix languages as this requires multiple processing actions.  So I would definitely recommend SSJS here (but I also really hate GTL) but I would recommend ONLY SSJS and no AMPscript.

Comment: Sure thing. This was a bit of a short version of the best practice :D
Not mixing languages would imply that you'll be best advised to keep all your email free of AMPScript because of this. So you do limit your options a bit, as AMPScript might well be in the template etc. already. On the other hand, be mindful of the issue, run a performance test, and if it's sufficient for the business case, go for it.

Comment: @JonasLamberty - I just like to point it out because there is a ton of misinformation in relation to SSJS leading to many people discounting SSJS as a viable language at all.  It is certainly viable and in many places is more useful than AMPscript. It all depends on context and use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work for your needs to output the stringified packages:

```html
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");

 //set your attributes to variables
 var email = Attribute.GetValue('emailaddr');
 var contactkey = Attribute.GetValue('Contact_Key');
 var customerNumber = Attribute.GetValue('CUSTOMERNR');
 var first_Name = Attribute.GetValue('FirstName');
 var allPackages = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Attribute.GetValue("Packages")).recipient.attributes.Packages;
 var packagesStr = Stringify(allPackages);

</script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <tr>
   <td align="center">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="550">

      <tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #4a4a4a; padding:px; line-height:24px; background:#F9F9F9;">
            <br>
            <ctrl:var name=packagesStr />
            <br>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Which outputs:

```json
[{"Name":"Entertainment","Price":"15 €","PaymentDate":"01.07.2020"}, {"Name":"Cinema","Price":"15 €","PaymentDate":"01.07.2020"}]
```

You can then iterate through the JSON as you would normally:

```javascript
var Name = allPackages[0].Name        //outputs Entertainment
var Price = allPackages[0].Price      //outputs 15 €
var obj2_Name = allPackages[1].Name   //outputs Cinema
var obj2_Price = allPackages[1].Price //outputs 15 €
```

When outputting SSJS variables inline, you need to use the ctrl tag. Like so:

```
<ctrl:var name=Name />   //outputs like AMPscript %%=v(@Name)=%%
<ctrl:var name=Price />  //outputs like AMPscript %%=v(@Price)=%%
```

When I ran the above, it ran in less than a second, so I do not foresee processing being an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with a simple approach by exactly pasting the above code to see if it renders anything but unfortunately I could still see the output as null. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you share your code because it output for me as shown in my answer. I get the feeling that there is a syntax or parsing issue going on

Comment: Code is exactly the same as yours (mentioned above by you). But in output I can only see the FirstName,EMail Address and other fields which have one value, but for Packages its Null

Comment: Verify your data structure matches what you provided - e,g. that the path `.recipient.attributes.Packages` is correct inside your `Packages` attribute pulled in. If it is different, then you will need to adjust this path to what is in your data.

Comment: To simplify and verify that the `Packages` attribute is coming across correctly, you can change the var `allPackages` to `Attribute.GetValue("Packages")` and the ctrl var name to `allPackages`

Comment: Thank you. So, this time I tried what you asked for and it came as blank (not even null like earlier).

Comment: That sounds like the issue is your data - verify that you have a value in the field 'Packages' in your sendable DE source.

Comment: @SourabMund If there is nothing coming in via your attribute then nothing can be parsed. Not sure why you removed the accepted answer and upvote but if nothing is coming through in the attribute then something is wrong outside the json parse which is something I can't really help with since I only have the info you provided above